# (NOT) IN list of values filter in CDS definitions

Tags: abap, cds

I am curious to know if CDS views have any filter commands similar to SQL's  `in ('value1', 'value2')`. It is not directly supported by CDS views, but it's supported by most versions of SQL (including Open SQL). I can always just check by writing out a long is or `Field = 'value1' OR Field = 'value2'`, but if such syntax exists, I would prefer to use the shorter syntax.

Open SQL example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Select * 
  from customers 
  where customer_group in ( 'group1', 'group2' )
  into table @lt_table.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ABAP CDS, probably not.

Here are the possible operators from the [ABAP 7.53 documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abencds_f1_conditional_expression.htm):

- `=`, `<>`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`
- `BETWEEN`
- `LIKE`
- `IS NULL`
- `IS INITIAL`

(there is also the boolean operator `NOT`)

As far as I can see, CDS Views in S/4HANA always use `OR`.